# How to run flink scala shell in yarn mode

Tags: apache-flink

I try to launch flink scala shell in yarn mode, but hit the following error.

This is the command I use, Do I miss anything ? Thanks

```
bin/start-scala-shell.sh yarn -n 2


Starting Flink Shell:
2018-06-04 17:31:18,166 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
2018-06-04 17:31:18,168 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2018-06-04 17:31:18,168 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2018-06-04 17:31:18,168 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.mb, 1024
2018-06-04 17:31:18,169 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
2018-06-04 17:31:18,169 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2018-06-04 17:31:18,169 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8081
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't deploy a standalone cluster.
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.StandaloneClusterDescriptor.deploySessionCluster(StandaloneClusterDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.StandaloneClusterDescriptor.deploySessionCluster(StandaloneClusterDescriptor.java:31)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.deployNewYarnCluster(FlinkShell.scala:272)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.fetchConnectionInfo(FlinkShell.scala:164)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.liftedTree1$1(FlinkShell.scala:194)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.startShell(FlinkShell.scala:193)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell$.main(FlinkShell.scala:135)
    at org.apache.flink.api.scala.FlinkShell.main(FlinkShell.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of flink do you use? If it is 1.5.0 there is known issue that scala shell does not work with flip-6 mode (enabled by default). You can try running it with legacy [mode](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/ops/config.html#legacy). There is already open JIRA [FLINK-8795](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-8795) for fixing it.